# Saving a Work Order from an Automation Script in Maximo

Tags: automation, maximo

I am trying to save a Work Order in Maximo through an automation script. My script triggers from an action launch point using the Assignment Table as the object. In my case a button labeled start under the assignments tab in work order is calling the script which is starting the assignment record and moving the status to INPRG, but then it does not save the Work Order itself. The user would have to click the start button, then click the save icon on the Work Order currently. I am trying to get the button to save the Work Order from the script, so they will not need to manually click save after hitting the start button.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result I needed by using getOwner() till I was at the Work Order level, then using getThisMboSet().save() from the owner. My button is now doing the things I need it to do to the Assignment record and saving the Work Order it belongs to when clicked.

Comment: Most of the time you should let the framework manage the saving of the objects. You could post your code and describe the behaviour you'd like to obtain so people here could propose good solutions.